# Move files to a directory based on partial filename

Tags: batch-file

I have files names like this:

- "Jeff W  ACE #20495 Bund Job Report Submitted 9 16 2020    -oOo-.msg"
- "Miguel M  ACE #21462 Ficus Job Report Submitted 9 15 2020    -oOo-.msg"
- "Sandy U  ACE #6624 99 Twin Crossing Job Report Submitted 9 17 2020    -oOo-.msg"

I need to move them to a directory based on the 4 or 5 digit number after the # in the name.  I found a batch file but it needs to have the directory name at the same location in the file name and the same length.

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.text') do (
set "filename1=%%~i"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "folder1=!filename1:~0,1!"
mkdir "!folder1!" 2>nul
move "!filename1!" "!folder1!" >nul
endlocal
)
```

How can I modify this batch file to search for the 4 or 5 digit number instead of the number having to be at a fixed place within the name? Thanks!

Comment: What about this: `for /F "tokens=1* eol=# delims=#" %%E in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S "* #*.msg"') do for /F "eol= " %%G in ("%%~nF") do md "%%G" 2> nul & move "%%E#%%F" "%%G\"`?

Comment: That worked really well, thank you! That's so much better than having someone do it manually for eight thousand *.msg files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use the following code to achieve your goal:

```cmd
rem /* Loop through (unhidden) files whose names contain the sequence ` #`;
rem    split the file names at the `#` character then (there should be only one);
rem    the part before `#` is available in `%%E`, the part after `#` in `%%F`: */
for /F "tokens=1* eol=# delims=#" %%E in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S "* #*.msg"') do (
    rem // Split off the first space-separated word from the second name part:
    for /F "eol= " %%G in ("%%~nF") do (
        rem /* Use that word as the name of a sub-directory and create it
        rem    (` 2> nul` suppresses error messages when it already exists): */
        md "%%G" 2> nul
        rem /* Actually move the currently iterated file into the sub-directory
        rem    (there will appear a prompt when the target file already exists;
        rem     to avoid that, use the `/Y` option of `move` to force overwriting,
        rem     or put `if not exist "%%G\%%E#%%F" ` in front of `move` to avoid
        rem     overwriting; append ` > nul` to suppress text `1 file(s) moved.`): */
        move "%%E#%%F" "%%G\"
    )
)
```